# Eclipse Maven Find Dependency from Class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project in my Eclipse. I can click on a class and Eclipse will open the "Type" navigator and it will display the class (`.class`) file, and maybe some source - if one is available - but how can I make Eclipse show me the **maven dependency or dependencies** that brought in that class?

EDIT: I know how to find the location in my local .m2 repo. What I am looking for is a way to know which maven dependency that class is associated.

For example, if I click on HTTPClient, Eclipse will tell me `The Jar file /Users/clangdon/.m2/repository/net/authorize/sdk/1.4.6.jar has no source attachment`, but how do I find out that this is associated to the maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on that class (somewhere in import)

if it open source and then

```
right click > show in package-explorer
```

it will show you jar from which it is coming under classpath

if it opens class name then on top it will have the jar name along with full file path from your local maven repository

once you find jar you, to find associated dependency you need to figureout group id and artifact and query maven dependency plugin

**For example**

for

```
/Users/clangdon/.m2/repository/net/authorize/sdk/1.4.6.jar
```

GAV are

```
groupId= net.authorize
artifactId=sdk
version=1.4.6
```

or you can go at this jar location and check its `pom.xml`  to get GAV

once you have these parameters you need to do

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="net.authorize:sdk"
```

on root pom of your project

Answer (score 2):

Open `pom.xml` with maven editor: right click on pom -> Open with -> maven pom editor.

Then open dependency hiearchy tab. Here you will find all you needs!

Comment: how do you map class to jar without knowing the detail ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes you are right. My method show you only who include declared jar, not which jar contains the class